# Is this a valid devise route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, registration

Hey guys is this a valid route to declare in the config/routes file? I want to a user to directed to a certain registration controller based on a condition but it doesn't seem to generate the route (when I do a rake routes command)

```
if Rails.application.config_for(:app)['app_for'] == 'vodacom'
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "vodacom/users/registrations"}
else
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations"}
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, routes are generated on app load, so whatever the initial value is what is going to be the route created. So only one of these two routes will work.

You can check in the controller, and if your condition is true, redirect them to the other controller. But just create both without the conditional and do the conditional in the controller and redirect.